# Create Oracle Warehouse Builder workspace in script

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, data-warehouse

I have been trying (and failing) to create a new workspace in Oracle Warehouse Builder using the Repository Assistant gui and [documentation](http://www.oracle86.com/ora_dir/owb.111/b31280/install_rep02.htm). After getting past the 10 configuration screens, the gui shows a progress dialog while it creates the workspace but then fails and the screen disappears without displaying an exception message.

I would prefer to use a script rather than the Repository Assistant gui to create the workspace mostly because the workspace creation should be part of a repeatable automated deployment process across environments but also because I think it will be easier to trace any exceptions back to the cause of the problem.

Are there any good resources that would help me to create an SQL script for workspace creation? It would seem to be something that others have accomplished before so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

The DB in question is hosted on a 4 node Solaris cluster and uses Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using the GUI, use OMB*Plus, its called Oracle Metabase you can write some routine using a combination of TCl/TK (tool command lnguage) and oracle metabase to solve your problem
good luck